# llamar una variable de vueJs en jQuery

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Buen dia, quisiera me ayudaran con lo siguiente, no di con el cuento de hacer autocomplete de un iput con Vue pues lo estoy aprendiendo, tengo un codigo de Jquery que me autocompleta ciudades, me sirve sin Vue pero yo armo el array con Vue, por lo cual necesito aceder a el

aqui el input el cual estaría creo yo dentro del tipico div de vue con id="app", correcto?

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="inputCiudades">
</div>
```

el script normalmente de jQuery va a asi y me funciona con el array ciudades

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var ciudades = [
      "Buenos Aires",
      "Santiago de chile",
      "Lima"  
    ];
    $( "#inputCiudades" ).autocomplete({
      source:ciudades
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

pero quisiera que la variable ciudades venga desde Vue

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
        ciudades:[],                
  },
  mounted(){
     this.consultarCiudades();
  },
  methods:{                    
      consultarCiudades(){

      //aqui armaré el array trayendo los datos de firestore lo cual lo se hacer
      //this.ciudades = .....
      }
)}
```

es esto posible?, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda mencionar que estas usando Vue.js v.2, puedes asignar una variable a la app

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
        ciudades:[],                
  },
  mounted(){
     this.consultarCiudades();
  },
  methods:{                    
      consultarCiudades(){

      //aqui armaré el array trayendo los datos de firestore lo cual lo se hacer
      //this.ciudades = .....
      }
  }
})
```

y Accede a la variable fuera de la app desde la variable de la app

```js
$( function() {
    var ciudades= app.ciudades;
    $( "#inputCiudades" ).autocomplete({
      source:ciudades
    });
  } );
```

Comment: @cKatoo lo hice tal cual y me da undefined, hice incluso una prueba mas sencilla con una funcion function prueba(){                 
                console.log(app.ciudades);
            } ejecutandola desde un boton y lo mismo, undefined, pusé la funcion al final luego de renderizar el vue, alguna idea?